# How to get add a new column value in output table, which activity cani use in Azure data factory

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory, kql, azure-data-explorer

[image]Trying to create a pipeline for copying data from REST API  to Kusto table,I get all the columns using mapping, but here I need to concat the 3 columns value into 1 column, how can I do where can I apply

I'm using ADF pipeline for copying data from REST API to Azure Kusto table, I'm able to get the all columns using mapping. But I Kusto table I need to concat the 3 column values into 1 column, how can I do, where can I do, is there any Kusto query updated or any activity add in pipeline.
Kusto query:
Tablename/extend workitemdatasourceid=strcat(tpid, servicearea,month)/project workitemdatasourceid

Comment: use dataflow to transform the column.

Comment: Im using pipeline with copy activity and foreach activity, we got data, but output table values to concat

Comment: I need 3 columns data into one column, how can write a Kusto function and this function where can I use in ADF, and how can I map

Comment: I attached a snap for mapping. Here I need to map custom.tpid, Custom.Month and Custom.ServiceArea=Workitemdatasourceid for sink side, I need 3 columns values into single column

Answer (score 0):

> How to get add a new column value in output table, which activity cani use in Azure data factory

To manipulate data, you need to use data flow activity in ADF. inside data flow add your source as rest API and sink as ADX (Kusto table).

- After source take a derived column activity and add column with your column name and in expression use `concat(column1,column2,column3)` it will give you the concatenated value of three columns.
  [image]
  to concat the values make sure all the column values are of string type or you can convert it into string by using `toString()` function.

Comment: First derived column take only concat column names na, next derived column take remaining columns right?

Comment: In source file REST API having multiple arrays, i need split the array and get the columns

Comment: can you add sample rest api output ?